# Convert Iterable tree to string

Tags: python, recursion, tree, formatting

I code this function to convert list of dict to a specific string to export last in a row table string field.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import types
import collections
from collections import Iterable

def convert_to_string(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return "{{{}}}".format(",".join(list("{}:{}".format(convert_to_string(key), convert_to_string(value)) for key, value in input.iteritems())))
    elif isinstance(input, list, tuple):
        return "[{}]".format(",".join(list(convert_to_string(element) for element in input)))
    elif isinstance(input, types.StringTypes):
        if isinstance(input, types.UnicodeType):
            return input
        if isinstance(input, types.StringType):
            return input.encode("utf8")
    elif isinstance(input, types.NoneType):
        return ""
    elif isinstance(input, (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType)):
        return "{}".format(input)
    else:
        try:
            return "{}".format(input)
        except:
            return "<Undefined>"

data = [[{"1": "pomme", "2": "poiré"}, u"pétrole"], [None, 4], [5.00, 6], 7, Iterable]
print (convert_to_string(data))
```

That return: in IPython

```
convert_to_string(data)
Out[18]: u"[[{1:pomme,2:poir\xe9},p\xe9trole],[,4],[5.0,6],7,<class '_abcoll.Iterable'>]"
print(convert_to_string(data))
[[{1:pomme,2:poiré},pétrole],[,4],[5.0,6],7,<class '_abcoll.Iterable'>]
```

Function work fine but do you know more efficient solution to do that?

Comment: Should the output format be strictly as you've shown, or you are allowed to vary/change it?

Comment: @alecxe What do you think about format "\r\n" in place of ","?

Comment: @alecxe I think the output can add replacement parameters for separator, dict and list delimiter, without enclosing... But final return is that I want actually. POO  can be a response to optimisation or factorisation with map and seconde function.

Comment: Thanks. I was initially thinking about using `json.dumps()` (and may be custom encoders), but was not happy with the result and decided not to post.

Comment: @alecxe are you talking about json.dumps(data, cls=ComplexEncoder) ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that, taking into account that `json` module knows how to serialize most of the things you have in your example..just a thought, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see if the code actually worked, because the `isinstance` should raise an exception:

```
    elif isinstance(input, list, tuple):
TypeError: isinstance expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

The second argument should be a tuple of types:

```
    elif isinstance(input, (list, tuple)):
```

but that might be a simply copy-over error.

---

In your code you do not need to force conversion to a `list`. The `.join` function can take an iterator as its argument. You free up a little memory for your program execution.

```
if isinstance(input, dict):
    return "{{{}}}".format(",".join(("{}:{}".format(convert_to_string(key), convert_to_string(value)) for key, value in input.iteritems())))
elif isinstance(input, list, tuple):
    return "[{}]".format(",".join((convert_to_string(element) for element in input)))
```

---

Since you already have imported the `types` module, I'd suggest that you be consistent, and use `types.ListType`, `types.DictType` etc. as well.